# Don't understand cause of this ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

```
score_board = []
for i in range(0, int(input())):
    score_board.append(int(input()))
new_board = sorted(list(set(score_board)), reverse=True)
print(new_board[1])
```

Getting Runtime Error.
Can someone suggest mean what mistake I'm doing in my code. I'm trying to upload code in hackerrank but i suggest below mentioned error. My code problem work on my laptop. I cant grasp the problem help me.Given the participants' score sheet for your University Sports Day, you are required to find the runner-up score. You are given  scores. Store them in a list and find the score of the runner-up.Print the runner-up score.

traceback:

```
Error (stderr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 3, in <module>
    score_board.append(int(input()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 6 6 5'
```

---

```
input (stdin)
`5`
`2 3 6 6 5`
```

Comment: The error message says it all: `"2 3 6 6 5"` can't be converted to a number. Do you mean `"23665"` or do you want to split the string and convert every single number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing **multiple** items to `append` which only accept a *single* item. If you want to add more than one item to your list at the same time, try using `extend`:

```
score_board = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    score_board.extend([int(x) for x in input().split()])
new_board = sorted(list(set(score_board)), reverse=True)
print(new_board[1])
```

This would work with your current input style. You also don't need to specify the `0` in the for loop, since it automatically starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to input number not string.

your input should look like this

```
5
2
3
6
6
5
```

Best regards